# How to list, add and remove repositories with yum python API?

Tags: python, repository, package, fedora, yum

How can I search for installed repostiries, add and delete them with yum python API (under fedora 17).
I've searched tons of websites and I have found how to manage packages (like here: http://phacker.org/2008/06/20/yum-python-api/), but I have not found anywhere how to handle repositories).

I want for example to be able to get with python yum API the same result as:

```
yum repolist
yum localinstall --nogpgcheck http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-stable.noarch.rpm http://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/fedora/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-stable.noarch.rpm`
```

(the last is simmilar to `yum-config-manager --add-repo; yum-config-manager --enable`)

etc.

Comment: The last is not *quite* the same; manipulating yum's repository information won't add the public signing key for the repository.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I fixed it in my question. Anyway - how to do both of them with python yum module?

Answer (score 2):

you can use [eulfedora](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/eulfedora)

> eulfedora.api provides complete access to the Fedora API, primarily
>   making use of Fedora's REST API. This low-level interface is wrapped
>   by eulfedora.server.Repository and eulfedora.models.DigitalObject,
>   which provide a more abstract, object-oriented, and Pythonic way of
>   interacting with a Fedora Repository or with individual objects and
>   datastreams.